# Add Non Scatter Chart Data For Use With OnClick

Tags: javascript, c3.js, scatter

Have a XY chart, I would like to relate year data to the data point so I can pass the year to an onclick message alert. I'm already retrieving the chart data. The attached shows two ways that I can retrieve the chart data, using d. and using signify() in case one method is more capable than the other. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/laguna92651/cptauo8c/)

Not sure where to place the year data in the code?
How would I retrieve the year for clicked on point to send to onclick Alert message?

```
       data: {
 xs: {
        'data1': 'x1',
        'data2': 'x2',
        'data3': 'x3',
        'data4': 'x4',
    },
columns: [
        ['x1', 10, 30, 45, 50, 70, 100],
        ['x2', 30, 50, 75, 100, 120],
        ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
        ['data2', 20, 180, 240, 100, 190]
    ],
   names: {
        data1: 'Oracle 1',
        data2: 'HP 2'
          }, 
  // Not sure where to place this data?
  // How would I retrieve year for clicked on point to send to onclick Alert message?
  //   [year1,2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2006]
  //   [year2,2000, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005]
```

Comment: I took a glance at your fiddle, why don't you define both of your arrays to a variable (without the string inside) and do sth like: `var clickYear = d.id == 'data1' ? year1Array[d.index]: d.id== 'data2'? year2Array[d.index] : null;`

Comment: Not sure what you are referring to (without the string inside). Where in the code I should place what you suggest, thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AkoyaP6618/cptauo8c/20/). I just reorganized some code and added commented on what's new.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'm using a Filemaker web viewer to host the code, and your code works in the web viewer pulling in external data, line 39 **Data**. When I try to use line15, in place of the Alert on line 18 the code breaks. I've used the line 15 code before, so it should work? See any problems. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/laguna92651/epyh7h5s/)

Comment: The expression that var theURL is equal to passes the allTogether parameter to a Filemaker script that calls a Filemaker message box showing the parameter parts; value, id, year etc. when I click on a data point.

Comment: Thanks, works great, fixed the problem, one too many commas. Could you explain how the 'var clickYear' works?  Why did you setup the onclick with the clickEvent  instead of using onclick: function (d)?

Comment: The `var clickYear` is using the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), you can also use if-else statements here and i've only setup the clickEvent to keep things more organized.

Comment: Is it possible to show the year in the tooltip?

Comment: sure, should be similar to the `onclick`, just look into the [reference](http://c3js.org/reference.html) and give it a [try](https://jsfiddle.net/AkoyaP6618/epyh7h5s/2/).

Comment: I noticed the the data points are connected in order of ascending x values, is it possible to connect the data points in order of the year array or at least in order of the data index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't post in the comments, but you could turn off sorting and ordering for the data. This would mean that you need to provide all data in the correct order each time you load it. This also uses an undocumented setting.

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/krsmith88/ajpsxfgg/) builds on what you are discussing above, note the change to the code:

```
....
data: {
    xSort: null,
    xs: {
....
```

Comment: xSort worked great. How can I modify the code for the variable for the  toolitp text so it can handle any number of data series without having to hard code the data series into the statement?       `var getYear = function(id, index){
 return id == 'data1' ? yearColumns.year1[index]: id== 'data2'? yearColumns.year2[index] : null;
}' Line 1 in this fiddle, [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/laguna92651/m6g19avz/5/)

Comment: Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/krsmith88/ojmy55bf/). Change the names of the properties that store your year and roa data from year1/2 and roa1/2 to data1/2 and then you can access the data using the series name.

Comment: Thanks, one last thing how would I add text to the tooltip title bar? For example would show AU: 30, instead of just 30.

Comment: You will need to add a tooltip title function to the generate call. [This](https://jsfiddle.net/krsmith88/3LL6wwut/) should do it for you.Can you mark this as answered if I've helped you?